# Refresh view on widget-like Tripadvisor app

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a widget that shows the last items of my website. There is an imageview to change the value of a widget (image, title, etc.) after clicking on it.

Now, I would like to make a refresh button like the Tripadvisor app (To rotate the icon until it gets some content).

Can I make an imageview with a start and stop function to handle this rotating icon?

**Updated**

I think, In the widget, I can not access directly to the view.

```
    remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.widgets_layout);
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please post some more code so that actual issue can be identified

Answer (score 0):

You should use rotation animation like this

```
RotateAnimation rotateAnim = new RotateAnimation(0, 360,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.5f);

    rotateAnim .setDuration(4000);
    rotateAnim .setRepeatCount(-1);
    yourView.setAnimation(rotateAnim );
```

and stop like this

```
yourView.clearAnimation();
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an AsyncTask, which runs on a background thread, and a ProgressBar.

This isn't the exact code, but it's an example of something I've used.

```
private void updatePicture(String url){

   AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> getNewPicture = new AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>() {

    /**
     * Your "start" method
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        // show the rotating icon
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progressBar.setActivated(true);
    }

    /**
     * The main task
     */
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        //get the updated icon...
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        .....

        return updatedPicture;
    }

    /**
     * The "stop" method
     */
     protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
         // hide ProgressBar and show image
         progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
     }      

    //run the task
    getNewPicture.execute(urlForUpdate);
}
```

You need to have the AsyncTask in its own method like this or you'll get an exception if you try to run it more than once. This way, every time you call UpdatePicture(), a new AsyncTask is created and ran.